# Cannot get serial port to read input on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, serial-port

I recently installed a startech PEX1S1P952 serial/parallel adapter card into a machine with Ubuntu 14.04. Output of `lspci -vv` shows the following on the card:

```
04:00.1 Serial controller: Oxford Semiconductor Ltd Device c101 (prog-if 02 [16550])
    Subsystem: Oxford Semiconductor Ltd Device c101
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin B routed to IRQ 44
    Region 0: I/O ports at c000 [size=8]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: serial
```

Output from `setserial -g /dev/ttyS*` shows the card on `/dev/ttS4`:

```
/dev/ttyS4, UART: 16950/954, Port: 0xc000, IRQ: 44
```

The card is currently hooked to an auxilary output port from a physiology amplifier, which is constantly emitting data and then passed into a null modem. However in minicom, no output is displayed and there is nothing in `/dev/serial/`.

When I use a serial to USB adapter on to the same connection instead of the serial port, Ubuntu assigns it to `/dev/ttyUSB0` and in minicom, the constant output stream is visible, and the device appears in `/dev/serial/by-id`.

Edit: Output from `stty --file=/dev/ttyACM0 --all`

`stty: /dev/ttyACM0: No such file or directory`

Is there anything I need to do to have minicom and presumably the OS recognize/accept data from this port?

I've added my user account to dialout and I've run minicom as sudo as well.

Edit: output from `stty --file=/dev/ttyS4 --all`

`speed 115200 baud; rows 0; columns 0; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^A; eol = <undef>;
eol2 = <undef>; swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R;
werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; flush = ^O; min = 0; time = 100;
-parenb -parodd cs8 -hupcl -cstopb cread clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk -brkint -ignpar -parmrk inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr -icrnl -ixon -ixoff
-iuclc -ixany -imaxbel -iutf8
-opost -olcuc -ocrnl -onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
-isig -icanon -iexten -echo -echoe -echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt
-echoctl -echoke`

Comment: Serial communication!  Wow... That's a trip down to memory lane.  ;-)  What does `stty --file=/dev/ttyACM0 --all` give you?  Please [edit] your question and add this information...

Comment: Hi Fabby, I added the information to my original post. Any ideas? I've been trying every whisper of a solution I can find online, but no luck so far.

Comment: ah, oops...  Copy-paste error...  `stty --file=/dev/ttyS4 --all`  **Sorry!!!  :-(**

Answer (score 0):

You keep mixing up the ports. Try looking with minicom to /dev/ttyS4
Remember the exact syntax, do not forget that capital S or the y as in your question.

Or do "sudo apt install cutecom". It is the same as minicom but graphical and it lists the attached devices so you can not miss.

(And as always with this TTL voltages you could bend two paperclips and fiddle them in port 5 (left upper) and the middle upper one and put this in your mouth with one hand suspended over a keyboard to get the data into a readable format. Use two hands for baud rates of 9600 and up.)